# Apex class APi version update

Tags: apex, api-version

could anyone suggest whether we can update API version of apex class through Apex/trigger. If i try to update ,i am getting DML operation not allowed on aepx classes.

Comment: Please check this link: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/87542/how-to-update-api-version-of-all-classes-in-single-go

Answer (score 4):

No, Apex Code can't directly modify a class or trigger without going through the API. This means that you'd have to call either the Metadata or Tooling API, which you could access via [financialforcedev/apex-mdapi](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi), for example. It would be a lot easier to access the API from outside Apex Code, such as JavaScript or Java (via an Applet) than to try and do this directly within Apex Code.